# executing sql query in UiPath to extract data from snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, uipath, uipath-activity

I am using execute query activity in Uipath studio and writing the sql query like this

> "select * from SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA where value=CALL_CENTER"

to extract the table values from snowflake.
where "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA" is the database and "CALL_CENTER" is the table which is present in the said database.

After I execute the query in uipath it gives the following error:

> Execute Query: ERROR [42S02] SQL compilation error: Object
> 'SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA' does not exist or not authorized.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Can you run this query in the Snowflake UI using the same role that you are using in uipath?

Comment: I have executed the query in snowflake worksheet. But its format was different like this select * from "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCDS_SF100TCL"."CALL_CENTER";  when I try to copy the same query to Uipath it gives me error.

Comment: What kind of error? The first select is wrong. You can't select on database. It is not a table\it has no columns. You need to specify schema/table like in the comment before this. That looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update your SQL query.

The correct syntax is SELECT * FROM [database.table];

If you want to pull everything from the table, you will need to enter the line below (in double quotes) in the **Sql** property of the **Execute Query** activity:

`SELECT * FROM SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.CALL_CENTER;`

Lastly, the output will need to go to a data table.

[image]